# Sorting an array by most occurrences of certain letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an `array` of words and the following list of letters:

> searoiltnudcypmhgbkfwvzxjq

I would like to sort the `array` by the letter order in this list, so that the word with the most amount of letters near the start of the list appears first. For example: the following:

```
var wordList = "nymph, races, tundra";
```

Once sorted, should be:

```
wordList = "races, tundra, nymph";
```

So far I have the following to assign a weight to each letter in the list:

```
  for (let h = 0; h < freqWords.length; h++) {
     this["freq" + h] = h; 
  }
```

Next I have to give each word in the array a value based on how many of these vars it contains and then sort the way from lowest value to highest value. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of the syntax to accomplish this.

Comment: `so that the word with the most amount of letters near the start of the list appears first` With what weights? Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: Hopefully I addressed your comment above. I'm stumped as to what to do moving forward.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - `{ freq0: 0, freq1: 1, freq2: 2 ...}`, what does that accomplish, and what is the `this`? You haven't shown the calling context (or even the function)

Comment: I was thinking I'd need a var with a value for each letter so that I could check that against each word in the array and get a value I can sort by. As far as the `this`, that was the only way I could get it to work, is that incorrect?

Comment: Just use a plain object instead, rather than mutating whatever the function's calling context is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it'll be a lot easier if you convert your letter list into an array and if you convert your word list to an array as well. Then, you're going to need to write a comparator function for `Array.prototype.sort` which counts the number of letters a supplied word has in a supplied array of letters. Here's an implementation that solves your problem:

```
const letters = [
  's', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'i', 'l', 't', 'n', 
  'u', 'd', 'c', 'y', 'p', 'm', 'h', 'g', 'b', 
  'k', 'f', 'w', 'v', 'z', 'x', 'j', 'q'
];

const wordList = [
  'nymph', 
  'races', 
  'tundra'  
];

console.log(wordList);

const sortedList = wordList.sort((a, b) => {
  const aOccurences = letterOccurences(letters, a);
  const bOccurences = letterOccurences(letters, b);
  return aOccurences - bOccurences;
});

console.log(sortedList);

function letterOccurences(letters, word) {
  let occurences = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (letters.includes(word.substring(i, i+1))) {
        occurences++;
    }
  }
  return occurences;
}
```

Input list: `nymph, races, tundra`

Result: `tundra, nymph, races` (6, 5, and 5 occurrences respectively.)

**EDIT:** If you need me to explain anything or if any of the syntax is unfamiliar, let me know.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Implemented this into a jotto playing program where the computers trying to guess a user inputted word and getting a huge improvement in amount of turns it takes to guess correctly.

Comment: @ItaiYasur Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

A shorter declarative functional-style alternative:

```
const letters = 'searoiltnudcypmhgbkfwvzxjq';
const input = "nymph, races, tundra"
const sorted = input.split(',').map(str => str.trim()).sort((aWord, bWord) => {

    const aCount = aWord.split('').filter(char => letters.includes(char)).length;
    const bCount = bWord.split('').filter(char => letters.includes(char)).length;

    return bCount - aCount;

});
```

Comment: Definitely a cleaner solution than the one I provided and utilizes his initial input without splitting letters and words into arrays beforehand.